# generate qr code from text fields zxing applet?

Tags: java, iphone, applet, qr-code, zxing

I am developing an app for iPhone that reads QR codes, but I need to generate this QR code as well from a PC that prints them,

I need my QR generating a text string like:

> Mike,Alistar,83503945,23/jun/1982,045,contactoSumbis,03982,0451053434,monio@gmail.com,45 cucll rd,white,no notes,4/feb/2012

But I need to make my custom form  like in the [zxing QR generator](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/)

to accommodate fields of my necessity, name, id, dob etc

so how to accomplish this?, can I change the Zxing qr generator forms, or is there another way,

thanks to @ron to pointing this link  but now i have the doubt is this for a java applet? how does it run in the web like in the link for the generator?,

because I saw the code [appspot code for contact form](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/zxing.appspot.com/src/com/google/zxing/web/generator/client/ContactInfoGenerator.java), now I have the doubt, because it looks like is for android, like importing events,,

so is what I should look at to a java applet?,

thanks!

Comment: You can get the source code for zxing.appspot.com from http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: @Rup, hi thanks, im using zxing librarie on my iphone app, but in the repo they only have a link for the qr generator, the source is for the reader?, or im missing the correct link?, thanks

Comment: It looks like the [encoder source is here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fcore%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fqrcode%2Fencoder) and [the appspot code is here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fzxing.appspot.com%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fweb%2Fgenerator%2Fclient) - is that not what you want? Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @Rup please see my edit, as I have a doubt of how it runs on the browser, applet?, code looks like for android?, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app has access to the Internet, you can call Google Charts directly.

URL encode your text string, then call

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
    cht=qr
   &chs=350x350
   &chld=L
   &choe=UTF-8
   &chl=Mike,Alistar,83503945
```

That will return a .png with the QR code.

You can change the size of the code an the level of error correction by altering &chs and &chld